# How can I show tiff extension on Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, c#, google-chrome, ext.net

I really need help for this problem. I searched it more than 2 days but i couldnt find any solution.

I have an application wrritten by ext.net framework at fronthand side. I have a problem related with showing tif file in a browser.You know some of browsers don't support tif file.Only IE and Saffari browsers support it.But I want to show it in Google Chrome browser.Also I want to not only view but also magnify and shrink to examine it.At this point, to meet my need what can I do.According to some research, It can be shown after conversion to other standart image format(png,jpg).Would you show me a way to overcome this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You'll have to convert the image to a different format using a back-end library or manually using Photoshop.

Comment: After some search, I found a solution at [http://rfvallina.com/blog/2015/08/22/preview-tiff-and-pdf-files-using-html5-file-api/].It converts tiff to png format using some library based on javascript.I want to magnify and shrink the png converted  to study and see more detailly.I have failed.

Comment: Working Link (http://rfvallina.com/blog/2015/08/22/preview-tiff-and-pdf-files-using-html5-file-api/)

Comment: This extension will convert tiff and allow zooming in and out, and moving around page.  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/inline-tiff-viewer/kkfncbfgbghoklckdmeljdjohpkknlma

Answer (score 0):

TIFF is not a format suitable for images on the Internet, and it is poorly supported. Instead, you should use:

- JPG for photos (JPG's compression is not lossless, but it's good for photos).
- PNG for ClipArts and schematics (it has lossless compression which is good for large uni-color surfaces).

The preferred way to convert would be to directly access the TIFFs on your server and to convert them, either with a graphical tool like GIMP or with a console batch converter like imagemagick (check their websites for demos).

I cannot recommend sending a TIFF to the client and let them convert it at every access. It sends too much data, results in a longer page load, decreases battery life of handheld devices and is much less portable.

Comment: I know TIFF is not a format suitable.But I have to work with tiff file, my customers have files whose format are TIFF.And I want to show it in a viewer on my web application based on ext.net fronthand like a pdf, org png.I am lookşng for a solution based on javascript at client or c# at backend.